# Top Users by Tag (suggestion for StackExchange)

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation

I love the fact the Users sort shows the people with the highest reputation but I think it would be super helpful to have top users by tags too. That way more people could standout for their efforts here and more people would be incented to contribute.

What I'm thinking is a list of top 10 tags above the users list that when clicked will take to a users screen with reputation ranking by that tag. The top 10 list could also have a link to all tags with links to top reputation users for each tag. That would also help people coming here to find people to hire to know who is best at what.

Comment: This should be moved to StackOverflow Meta.

Comment: If you want to propose a system-wide change, I think you better do this on [the Stack Overflow Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Currently we already have [stats per tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=plugins&sort=stats&pagesize=15), so make sure to point out where your proposal differs from this. Since your regular SO profile now has more than 200 rep, if you de-associate and then re-associate your Meta SO profile, you will get a +100 boost there, so you don't look like a newbie.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Thanks for the link to stats per tag. I wasn't aware of it (which is the key problem) and I also find it very confused. My proposal would be to make it more prominent on the users page; i.e. a single row tag across the top of the user page above the users that when clicks on would take the visitor to a page formatted the same as the user page but filtered by the tag and with a prominent heading that makes the filtered tag clear.

Comment: I will head over the Stack Overflow Meta and thanks for the tip. However, can you tell me how to de-associate my profile because in that respect I **am** a newbie. :)

Comment: @Arlen Beller: How does one *"move"* a question to another site? Or do you mean I should post it over there too? (which I now plan to.)

Comment: @Mike: Indeed, you can't (yet) move a question like you can between the original sites. So just re-ask and provide a link so we can support you :-). To de-associate, go to your SO user page, click on the "accounts" tab at the right, and then the "Clear all associations" button at the bottom. This will remove associations (which is harmless), after which you can re-associate by clicking the buttons for each site.

Comment: Please make sure to include a link here to your question there.  Also, I suggest requesting that it not be limited to only the top 10 tags.  Maybe those should be most immediately visible, but I could see a lot of value in being able to find who is the most helpful for some obscure, niche tag.

Comment: The limit I was proposing for the top 10 tags was just for the main user page so as not to overwhelm the main user page. I was assuming a link to a page with all the tags. I think I'll wireframe this with Balsamiq before I post to meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. I have some other obligations so I can't do it at the moment but will soon.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know when it has been implemented, but it happened. Each tag has a link named **top users**, and here you get a nice list.

Example from our <s>over</s> *most* used tag [plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins):

[image]

Comment: Been implemented as long as I can remember...

Comment: Then someone should spend the question a `<status-completed>` tag (if that helps to prevent the question being pulled by the bot, that is), or an answer should be marked accepted.