# Tags are getting out of control - sky is the limit

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, suggestion

### The current situation

Currently we got a rough number of 900+ tags. Which is much too much. Even with having this filter, it's more than anyone could search, as we have different variations of the same tag over and over again.

Now people file their questions under a variety of tags that all say the same to them.

*Example:*

> »I want to change something on this URl.«
>
> Here's part of the tags under which people are filing their questions.
>
> [url-rewriting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) [rewrite-rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-rules) [add-rewrite-rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-rewrite-rule) [rewrite-tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-tag) [mod-rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) [rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) [htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess)

This is **not good**. Some of the above mentioned tags are merely the same like [url-rewriting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) and [rewrite-rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite-rules), but the others are targeting completely different stuff.

### What we already did

> - We discussed - started by Rarst - [if they are important to us](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/how-important-are-tag-wikis) - without a final decision (or much attention to that topic).
> - [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and all its relevants got added to the **blacklist** as a result [of this discussion](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/why-wordpress-tag-on-wordpress-answers).
> - Mike even [suggested a high rep user tag](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/top-users-by-tag-suggestion-for-stackexchange) - still open for that one ;)
> - Finally toscho suggested a [»tag soup cleanup«](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/tag-soup-clean-up).

### Toolset we already have

A) Our moderators to merge, delete, etc. tags.

B) Us to correct the wrong tags: Just hover over the tags and you'll find a link to edit in line. This is fast and nice.

> [image]

### Where's the problem?

So as we already cleaned up all first answers, close votes, etc. we now can try to get on cleaning up our »Tag Soup« <sup>(tm) toscho</sup>.

But before we're getting at this, we need a little help from the **SE Network-Team** to close a gap: The [`create-tags`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) has a **minimum required reputation of only 300(!) points**. That is **much too less**. Imagine how often someone would need to go and clean up tags like:

[wordpress-plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) and [plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins)

[plugin-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development) and [wordpress-plugin-dev](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin-dev)

Those tags pop out like mushrooms after a rainy, wet day.

### Suggestion:

Raise the rep-limit until a user is allowed to create a tag to 5k - or even better to 10k.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that has to go away are tags as clones of function names. We have a search engine. Tags are for concepts, for topics spanning multiple steps.

Also don't forget the main use case for tags is the [automatic suggestion of similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions).