# Please add quick tag edit to question list

Tags: feature-request, tags

When reading through a list of questions, I often see tags that really don't belong to the question. In fact, nearly every second question has tags attached that don't belong there. I really like the quick edit possibility on tags (and the fact that it doesn't count in the amount of edits one can make before it becomes a community wiki), but we'd really need a faster possibility. Tags are completely out of control over here. Just take a look at the other meta threads about tags (too low limit to add new ones, so they pop up like mushrooms after a rainy day: again and again and again).

> Please add the quick tag edit functionality to questions list and when possible attach a limit of min. 2k to it, so it doesn't gets missused to quickly.

For the question/feat. request about reputation limits, read [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/tags-are-getting-out-of-control-sky-is-the-limit).
Thanks.

*Feedback by the SO/SE team appreciated.*

Comment: I think that a 1.5K rep limit would be better - 2K already allows you to edit posts, but there's no permissions between 1K and 2K

Comment: Re-tagging questions only requires 500 exp. I would think that a quick-edit of tags should be the same?

Comment: And tag creation needs 300exp. Please see the update and the linked question.

Comment: Indeed, tag proliferation is a problem. I'm merely advocating that a tag quick-edit reputation limit should be consistent with the normal tag-edit reputation level, *even if the normal tag-edit reputation level needs to be increased*.

Comment: Does this kind of Question has any traction/relevance here, or should it be made directly in [meta.se]? Is this comment meta-meta?